# How to upload image to SQL with MVC3 within one Form using ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-3, ado.net, razor

I am having trouble putting image upload field within the rest of the fieldset, mainly becaouse i need two Actions for one Form, correct me if I am wrong! Aloso when using Model to render fields in View, there is no @Html.UploadField or similar.... Any ideas?

My goal is to save image in the same row as the rest of the form...

**MODEL:**

```
 public class MyModel
 {
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Author: ")]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Title: ")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }

}
```

**VIEW:**

```
@model namespace.MyModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddForm", "Admin"))
{

<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>New Article</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Author)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Author)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Author)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)
        </div> 
         <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title)
        </div>

         @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveImage", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {   
            <div class="editor-label">Image</div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <div>Upload image: <input type="file" name="Image" /></div>
            </div>

        }

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</div>
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
 //AddForm
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddForm(MyModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AdminServices"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into MyTable(DbAuthor, DbTitle) values(@author, @title)", connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author", model.Author);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", model.Title);

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
    }

    //SaveImage
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveImage(MyModel zan, HttpPostedFileBase image)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (image != null)
            {
                zan.ImageMimeType = image.ContentType;
                zan.ImageData = new byte[image.ContentLength];
                image.InputStream.Read(zan.ImageData, 0, image.ContentLength);


                string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AdminServices"].ConnectionString;

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into MyTable(DbImage) values(@image)", connection))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", zan.ImageData);
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
            }

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
    }
```

My problem is to put these two methods into one, and to have native MVC3 uploadfield in View...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your viewmodel, declare the image field as an HttpPostedFileBase like so:

```
public HttpPostedFileBase ImageData { get; set; }
```

In the view, make sure you have both the ID and NAME attributes of the file input correspond to the name of the property on your viewmodel:

```
<input type="file" name="ImageData" id="ImageData" />
```

When you submit the form, the uploaded file will be populated into the HttpPostedFileBase property by the default model binder.

Also, your Html.Form needs to wrap all of the input fields, not just the file upload. Having nested forms is invalid in HTML.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddForm", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, 
    new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>New Article</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Author)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Author)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Author)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)
        </div> 
         <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title)
        </div>  
        <div class="editor-label">Image</div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <div>Upload image: 
                <input type="file" name="ImageData" id="ImageData" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</div>
}
```

**Update**

I cannot answer the ADO.NET part of the question. We use EF 4.1 with the above approach, saving to a database table through an entity property. EF takes care of the ADO.NET part for us, so I'm not sure what the code would be using bare ADO.NET.

Comment: @oliverhour - thanks, can you just explaine how to save this with ado.net in one method, including image that was uploaded?