# EntityType 'HttpPostedFile' has no key defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When I start my MVC App, this error comes upp
"EntityType 'HttpPostedFile' has no key defined"

Can someone please tell me whats wrong here?

Model:

```
public partial class Advert
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public HttpPostedFile ImageData { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UrlToUse { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int SchemaType { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

When the controller get hit, I run this

```
    public ActionResult DisplayAdvert()
    {
        db.Database.CreateIfNotExists();

        return PartialView("_Advert");
    }
```

And boom, at the line db.Database.CreateIfNotExists(); it fails:

Boat_Club.Models.HttpPostedFile: : EntityType 'HttpPostedFile' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
HttpPostedFiles: EntityType: EntitySet 'HttpPostedFiles' is based on type 'HttpPostedFile' that has no keys defined.

I've searched for some answers, and all says that I have to add [Key] to the Model, and I have, so what is going on here??

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web, with all the latets versions of MVC and EF.

/Thanks

This works though!!

```
public partial class Advert
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UrlToUse { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int SchemaType { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly do not use `HttpPostedFile` in your model, it's not supposed to be serialized anywhere.

Instead declare your image data as `byte[]`, or if you need more details as well create another type to hold those, then transfer the required details across from the posted file instance.

For example:

```
public partial class Advert
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UrlToUse { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int SchemaType { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just tried that, and it works! Saw in another post here at SO, to use HttpPostedFileBase, is that possible! [SO Post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777623/how-to-upload-image-to-sql-with-mvc3-within-one-form-using-ado-net)

Comment: Unsure but I personally still wouldn't use those types directly.

Comment: Tried HttpPostedFileBase, no luck there. So I'm going with byte[], makes more sense, to me!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Your ORM (probaly EF here) believes that `HttpPostedFile` is an entity from your database, and that `ImageData` is a navigation property.

When you get an `HttpPostedFile` or `HttpPostedFileBase` in your controller, you should get its content as a `byte[]`, then pass it to your `Advert` entity.  Here's an exemple : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream(v=vs.110).aspx